# How to website logout click using webbrowser1

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET, i want click logout link using webbrowser or another component.
Thanks for help.

```
<a class="end" href="#" onclick="document.logoutForm.submit(); return false;">Logout</a>
```

Comment: "webbrowser or another component" are not equal in case of asp.net...you cannot use webbrowser component in it..Instead you can use anchor links as how you did.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need even "onclick" event. You do not need to post because logout.aspx page is only meant to kill the current user session so GET request (which is default) is enough.

```
<a class="end" href="logout.aspx">Logout</a>
```

Inside, logout.aspx codebehind file you can kill the current session.

Inside logout.aspx page_load event:

```
Session.Clear()
Session.Abandon()
```

Comment: sorry i want auto click this link using vb.net

Comment: What do you mean by auto click? If you want to logout the user by firing click event of logout url using some code then either you can send ajax request to logout.aspx page or redirect to logout.aspx depending upon your need.

Comment: theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
            If curElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Sign in") Then
                curElement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next